# HTMLFormElement null is not assignable to parameter of type string | Typescript | EmailJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React Typescript is prevent me from being able to use the boilerplate code from [emailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/).

I have modified the boiler plate code to fix one error on the UseRef() and const sendEmail.

I am getting the error on the form.current line in function sendForm().

Error:
(property) React.RefObject.current: HTMLFormElement | null

Argument of type 'HTMLFormElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLFormElement'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLFormElement'.ts(2345)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of error is why I love TypeScript ;)

The compiler is smart enough to understand that `form.current` can contain a form, or it could be `null`, so it is typed as `HTMLFormElement | null`.

In your `sendEmail` function you are not accounting for this case in any way, so the compiler is yelling and whining and is completely right!

You must account for the case in which `form.current` is null:

```
  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const currentForm = form.current;
    // this prevents sending emails if there is no form.
    // in case currentForm cannot possibly ever be null,
    // you could alert the user or throw an Error, here
    if (currentForm == null) return;

    // the compiler is smart enough to know that currentForm here is of type HTMLFormElement 
    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', currentForm, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. I am not a fan of typescript currently.